# How and what tools and I need to use spike in bare metal risc-v?

Tags: riscv, toolchain, bare-metal

I need to make a program that has access in machine mode (M) for that reason I need to run it on bare metal (without pk). I have installed the following risc- v tools: **riscv64-unknown-elf-xxx**, **spike**.

I tried to follow these [steps](https://github.com/ucb-bar/libgloss-htif) but got the following [error](https://github.com/ucb-bar/libgloss-htif/issues/8)

How can I generate a bare metal binary using riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc and simulate with spike?